# How to make Post Thumbnail with read more with its full size?

Tags: javascript

**How to make Post Thumbnail with read more with its full size ?
This is the code of read more in blogger that i am using with blogger everything is ok
but the post Thumbnail is re-sized to 300 * 300 and i want it to be with its full size and also be horizontal center and also the text of summery of post be under Post Thumbnail not beside it**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
summary_noimg = 460;
summary_img = 460;
img_thumb_height = 300;
img_thumb_width = 300;
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[

function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){ 
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    {
        var s = strx.split("<"); 
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
            } 
        } 
        strx =  s.join(""); 
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...'; 
}

function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if(img.length>=1) { 
        imgtag = '<span style="float:left; margin:0px 10px -46px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height+'px"/></span>';
        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}

//]]>
</script>
```

i have tried to change that

```
summary_noimg = 460;
summary_img = 460;
img_thumb_height = 300;
img_thumb_width = 300;
```

be

```
summary_noimg = 460;
summary_img = 460;
img_thumb_height = 100%;
img_thumb_width = 100%;
```

**but it is not working so what can i do ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`summary_noimg = 460;
summary_img = 460;
img_thumb_height = "100%";
img_thumb_width = "100%";`